# Alpha blending only working on 5 of 6 sides on a cube

Tags: opengl

I'm rendering a cube with a texture mapped to all sides of it and somehow the alpha channel from the texture isn't being applied on one side of the cube. all other sides are rendered properly (transparent) but there's one side that is completely opaque. I've tried to change ordering of the vertices being used to render the quad and played around with tweaks on the texture coordinates but nothing seems to take effect.

This is the setup of the texture blending

```
glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

// bind Texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
// set the texture wrapping parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);    
// set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
// set texture filtering parameters
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The code is gathered from the LearnOpenGL repository and there are some files included to simplify loading shaders and textures. The code builds with CMake on Ubuntu 22.04 as well as on Arch Linux and leverages GLFW3 and GLM.

The vertices are specified as:

```
float vertices[] = {
// positions            // normals          // texture coords
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f, 0.75f,
 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.75f,
 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.25f,
 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.25f,
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f, 0.25f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.5f, 0.75f,

-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,     0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 0.75f,
... continued...
```

[image: cube rendered]
In the image above, it's apparent that the leftmost quad is opaque, while the other sides are transparent (as expected).

Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the drawing order of the triangles and the depth buffer.
The first drawn triangle uses the alpha blending against the background color.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

But even if it draws a transparent pixel, the depth buffer is updated with its Z position.

So when you draw a new triangle behind the exiting front one, it CANNOT be drawn because the depth buffer Z is lower than the current drawn Z.

***Solutions***

1.Disable depth buffer before rendering the transparent triangles. That way, all the triangles will be drawn independently the order you draw them. And reenable it when you finish.

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
/* draw the translucent cube here */
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

2.Sort the faces (triangles) to be drawn from back to front (aka painter's algorithm) using the distance to the camera position as the reference.

3.Discard the transparent pixel in the Shader with `discard()`. That way depth buffer is not updated and triangles behind this one can be drawn filling the holes (discard pixels). This only works for transparent, not for alpha blending, translucent object. It can impact performance.

**Recommendations**
Option 2 is the best one, but if you move the camera, or move/rotate the object. The faces need to be reordered. The vertices that are part of a face don't need to be sorted.

**Note about CULL_FACE**
I guess that you are drawing the back face of some faces. So GL_CULL_FACE is disable. You don't need to sort the triangles of a face to look to the camera, you can just disable CULL_FACE to draw them.

Comment: Amazing response!!! Works perfectly! Have only tried option one which is easy, but will absolutely investigate the better option.